# Problems setting up a postgreSQL database for a django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm new to Python/Django so forgive me if this is a simple problem to solve...

I'm trying to set up a PostgreSQL database for my Django project. I have downloaded PostgreSQL 9.2 from here http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/ and gone through the installation process. I've been following a wiki article which said to update my system path to /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin, which I have. When I type 'nano ~/.bash_profile' into Terminal I see this 'PATH ='Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin' which I believe means I have updated my system path correctly. However, when I then try to run the command 'createdb', I see this...

```
-bash: createdb: command not found
```

I believe I have installed PostgreSQL correctly so I'm not sure how to get around this.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you

Jess

Answer (score 2):

PATH ='Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin is overwriting your global $PATH with just the PostgreSQL binaries. It should be the following instead:

```
PATH="$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin"
```

This appends the PostgreSQL bin directory to your $PATH, instead of overwriting it. Don't forget to start a new terminal session after you make the edit, or do the following in your current session:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

In general, the best way to install open source software, packages and utilities on OSX is to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Homebrew is a package manager for OSX to simplify the installation and management of programs such as PostgreSQL, and many other popular open source projects. Check it out!

Comment: Thank you. I'll get homebrew. Just to make sure I'm doing it correctly, to update my system path to PATH="$PATH:Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin" do I use 'nano ~/.bash_profile', then edit the text after 'PATH = ' and then save by using ^X to Exit and then Y to save the changes? Sorry if this is really simple - it's my first time.

Comment: Yeah if you want to use a command line editor, but it might be more straightforward to use TextEdit. Run this and replace the line with the one I wrote above when TextEdit opens:

    open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Sorry to send another question your way! I've just tried to run 'python manage.py runserver' and the response I'm getting is 'Error: No module named psycopg2.extensions'. Do you know how I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not exactly an answer to your "question", it might solve the problem for you.  Have you checked out the PostgreSQL "app"?  It's created by Matt Thompson & supported by Heroku Postgres and is meant to make PostgreSQL development easier for people using Mac.  You might want to give it a look.  Here's a [link](http://postgresapp.com/).  Or just google "Postgresapp".

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the link. I've downloaded it and just tried to open the app but I'm being told it doesn't work with my version of Mac OS X (which is 10.6.8).

Comment: @Jess Well, sorry it wasn't of any use to you.  I hope you figure things out.  I use Django + PostgreSQL all the time and love it, but I'm on Linux.