# Error: No module named psycopg2.extensions

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to set up a PostgreSQL database for my django project, which I believe I have done now thanks to the replies to my last question [Problems setting up a postgreSQL database for a django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710715/problems-setting-up-a-postgresql-database-for-a-django-project/12713737#comment17168054_12713737). I am now trying to run the command 'python manage.py runserver' in Terminal to get my localhost up but when I run the command, I see this response...

```
Error: No module named psycopg2.extensions
```

I'm not sure what this means - I have tried to download psycopg2 but can't seem to find a way to download psycopg2 using homebrew. I have tried easy_install, pip install and sudo but all return errors like this...

```
Downloading http://www.psycopg.org/psycopg/tarballs/PSYCOPG-2-4/psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz
Processing psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-l7Qi62/psycopg2-2.4.5/setup.cfg
Running psycopg2-2.4.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-l7Qi62/psycopg2-2.4.5/egg-dist-tmp-PBP5Ds
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You don't have a compiler installed, and you need one to build the psycopg2 package. If you can provide details about your operating system, people here can probably help you with that.

Comment: @IanClelland Thanks Ian. I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.8. I have homebrew installed if that helps.

Comment: Check what you are using interpreter from the right venv.

Answer (score 204):

The first thing to do is to install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
sudo apt install python3-psycopg2 # Python 3
```

After that go inside your virtualenv and use:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

These two commands should solve the problem.

Comment: For Python 3, `sudo apt-get build-dep python3-psycopg2`

Comment: What's the point of building the dependencies with apt, then installing with pip?  What's wrong with the single command `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2`?  It worked fine for me.

Comment: got `You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list` while triyng any of the above commands

Comment: I'm new to python. Where shall I execute the: sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2

Comment: @nba2020: sudo apt-get...? These are linux (debian/mint/ubuntu) prerequisities for psycopg2-binary. If you use windows or such something you should find windows prerequisities for psycopg2-binary instead and apply them before installing psycopg2-binary. Or maybe (I'm not sure) you can skip prerequisities and install psycopg2 instead of psycopg2-binary and it could work. However psycopg2 (without -binary) is deprecated so it will be better if you try install psycopg2-binary correctly.

Comment: This answer is misleading, since the error asked about is actually solved by the pip command, not the apt-get install one.

Comment: This only worked for me, when I ran first command also inside virtualenv

Comment: it worked for me with the command: sudo apt install python3-psycopg2 # Python 3
without installing it in my venv... but why?

Answer (score 43):

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.

Comment: This doesn't help me enough. Somewhere in the history I have installed psycopg2 and later (from: -r requirements.txt) properly psycopg2-binary. Everything worked "fine". But once I uninstalled psycopg2 (without -binary) I received the "No module named psycopg2.extensions" error. Uninstall/install psycopg2-binary doesn't help me. For me the prererequisities were not installed (see @FernandoMunoz answer: apt install build-dep python-psycopg2). Installing these Debian packages and later(!) psycopg2-binary has helped me.

Answer (score 10):

For `Django 2` and `python 3` install `psycopg2` using `pip3` :

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: if you want to avoid building from source install `psycopg2-binary` instead

Answer (score 6):

I installed it successfully using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 6):

For `macOS Mojave` just run `pip install psycopg2-binary`. Works fine for me, python version -> `Python 3.7.2`

Answer (score 4):

first install `apt-get install python-setuptools`

then try `easy_install psycopg2`

Answer (score 4):

This is what helped me on Ubuntu if your python installed from Ubuntu installer. I did this after unsuccessfully trying 'apt-get install' and 'pip install':

In terminal:

```
sudo synaptic
```

then in synaptic searchfield write

```
psycopg2
```

choose

```
python-psycopg2
```

mark it for installation using mouse right-click and push 'apply'. Of course, if you don't have installed synaptic, then first  do:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issues recently and this code worked.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev-is-python3
```

Then

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.4, while in a virtual environment, make sure you have the build dependencies first:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-psycopg2
```

Then install it:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Answer (score 2):

On Alpine Linux (majority of the docker containers) do:

```
apk add postgresql-dev
```

Then:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the extension after only importing psycopg2:

```
import psycopg2

...

psycopg2.extensions.AsIs(anap[i])
```

Comment: @f p Thanks for your reply. How did you import psycopg2? Did you use homebrew? I've tried running the command 'import psycopg2' in my Terminal but it returns 'ImportError: No module named psycopg2'.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu where it's ready to install without compiling.. The example shown is in python. To install in windows look at http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/ What you want is to install it first.

Comment: @f p Thank you. I'm on mac - is there a similar solution for mac?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need `gcc-4.0`, and it would be helpful to specify your OS type and version.

Maybe this question will help you a bit: [Installing GCC to Mac OS X Leopard without installing Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360110/installing-gcc-to-mac-os-x-leopard-without-installing-xcode)

**Update**

I'm a Windows user, so I can't test your setup, but a quick google pointed to some more links:

- http://hardlifeofapo.com/psycopg2-and-postgresql-9-1-on-snow-leopard/
- [Cannot install psycopg2 on OSX 10.6.7 with XCode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427157/cannot-install-psycopg2-on-osx-10-6-7-with-xcode4)

Comment: Thank you. I've downloaded and installed GCC 10.6 as my OS is 10.6.8. I then ran easy_install psycopg2 but it returned this error...
"no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1". Do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the `No module named psycopg2.extensions` error when trying to run `pip2 install psycopg2` on a Mac running Mavericks (10.9). I don't think my stack trace included a message about gcc, and it also included a hint:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

I looked for the `pg_config` file in my Postgres install and added the folder containing it to my path: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin`. Your path may be different, especially if you have a different version of Postgres installed - I would just poke around until you find the `bin/` folder. After doing this, the installation worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
 **sudo pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi psycopg2==2.7b2**
.. this is especially helpful if you're running into egg error

on aws ec2 instances if you run into gcc error; try this 
**1. sudo yum install gcc python-setuptools python-devel postgresql-devel

2. sudo su - 

3. sudo pip install psycopg2**

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1):

I had such problem when trying to run python script as a sudo, while psycopg2 was installed via pip3 to my own user's directory.

I managed to resolve the issue for myself removing pip3 version, and just installing it via apt:

```
pip3 uninstall psycopg2
sudo apt install python3-psycopg2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install django-psycopg2-extension
```

I know i am late and there's lot of answers up here which also solves the problem. But today i also faced this problem and none of this helps me. Then i found the above magical command which solves my problem :-P . so i am posting this as it might be case for you too.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

you can install gcc for macos from  https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer 
after instalation of gcc you'll be able to install psycopg with `easy_install` or with `pip`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed psycopg2 if not

```
sudo apt-get install psycopg2
```

Install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
```

These two commands should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error raise because you not install postgres database in you project virtutal environment. you should run one of these command.
from a terminal you can you command for sudo.

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2
```

for pip (pip basically work for python)

```
pip install psycopg2
```

or

```
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

i'm pretty sure it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Below commands worked for me on Mac OS

```
   brew install libpq
   pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Run from Windows cmd:
py -m pip install psycopg2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).