# AttributeError: 'settings' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Examined the documentation of django and this post [Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root)  but, I'm still having issues, at first It was a SQlight issue so, I updated to latest Django from Django 2 now I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'MEDIA_Root'

```
Settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
```

Also tried this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
```

Comment: `'MEDIA_Root'STATIC_URL = '/static/'` is a syntax error for starters…!?

Comment: that was a copy and paste mistake not issue with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the comma at the end:

Bad Code:

```py
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
```

Good Code:

```py
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you actually imported wrong `settings`. Re-check your actually code. Instead of importing this (upper-case):

```
from django.conf import Settings
```

you should import this (lower-case)

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Also, as was pointed in comments, this is an error (or you incorrectly pasted the code here):

```
'MEDIA_Root'STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: I put Settings.py to make sure the code was categorized and easier to read. It has no function then it being a TAB on Tree view in the ATOM editor. settings is all lower case.

Comment: @DrGoat perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839276/4996863) answer will spear light on your problem?

Comment: The 8 year old post you linked got me into hair pulling mode. I looked for 2/3hrs and got my self into a (urls.E004)Your URL pattern issue. I reverted to the past code and restarted the server but, nothing is working. its stuck in that ERROR

Comment: Ok, let go harder way - post an exception trace.

Comment: I figured out what happened with the urls.0004 Error I put a Comma next to media example> ('media'), but, before it was ('media') I reverted this change but,the error is not changing.

Comment: Thanks for the Help Charnel. Can you please up mark my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I did a mistake on the name part.

I was getting

```
 Settings' object has no attribute 'STATIC'
```

My code was :

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC.ROOT)
```

My Code should have been :

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```