# Error: No module named psycopg2.extensions django postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-postgresql

I  want to Use PostgreSQl With Django  . I referred [this](http://paintincode.blogspot.in/2012/08/install-postgresql-for-django-and.html) tutorial to install it and when I run this command

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I get the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.creation import DatabaseCreation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/creation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2.extensions
ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions
```

I also Saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728004/error-no-module-named-psycopg2-extensions) and executed this

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
pip install psycopg2
```

However I still get the same error after doing this

Comment: Did the pip install psycopg2 actually successfully run?  I noticed your initial command used sudo, but the 2nd command did not.

Comment: @JosephPaetz Lol ! your Correct Man . Great . Thanks it just worked .. Post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure all packages being installed are being done so using **sudo**; otherwise, the installation will likely fail and you may not notice the error message indicating the failure was a result of permission issues.

Comment: one more help , can you give me a link where I can get screen shots and code for django application dev. with some example and learn quickly as possible

Comment: I think the universal answer is to walk your way through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/#first-steps) and go from there.

Comment: I find it to be a bit slow and also they dont take an example and explain and there aren't any screenshots, looking for a tutorial like developing a web app something like facebook demo