# ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions when rubber gem

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, rubber

I get this error when i call  cap rubber:create_staging
Im using a Ubuntu machine.

so far i have been mainly focusing on making changes to local_settings.py but did not get anywhere with that.

Here is what i get when I ran  pip freeze:

```
Django==1.5.4
Jinja2==2.7
Mako==0.8.1
MarkupSafe==0.15
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.0.0
Pygments==1.6
South==0.8.4
Sphinx==1.1.3
Twisted-Core==13.0.0
Twisted-Names==13.0.0
Twisted-Web==13.0.0
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.3
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
chardet==2.0.1
command-not-found==0.3
configglue==1.1.2
debtagshw==0.1
defer==1.0.6
dirspec==13.10
distribute==0.6.37
docutils==0.11
duplicity==0.6.21
httplib2==0.8
lxml==3.2.0
oauthlib==0.5.1
oneconf==0.3.5
pexpect==2.4
piston-mini-client==0.7.5
protobuf==2.4.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycrypto==2.6
pycups==1.9.63
pycurl==7.19.0
pygobject==3.10.0
pyinotify==0.9.3
pyserial==2.6
pysmbc==1.0.13
python-apt==0.8.9.1ubuntu1
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu1
pyxdg==0.25
reportlab==2.6
rhythmbox-ubuntuone==13.10
roman==1.4.0
rubber==1.1
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
six==1.3.0
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
stevedore==0.14.1
system-service==0.1.6
ubuntuone-storage-protocol==13.10
unity-lens-photos==1.0
virtualenv==1.11.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
xdiagnose==3.6.1
zope.interface==4.0.5
johnk@johnk-HP-EliteBook-8530w:~$  pip freeze 
Django==1.5.4
Jinja2==2.7
Mako==0.8.1
MarkupSafe==0.15
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.0.0
Pygments==1.6
South==0.8.4
Sphinx==1.1.3
Twisted-Core==13.0.0
Twisted-Names==13.0.0
Twisted-Web==13.0.0
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.3
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
chardet==2.0.1
command-not-found==0.3
configglue==1.1.2
debtagshw==0.1
defer==1.0.6
dirspec==13.10
distribute==0.6.37
docutils==0.11
duplicity==0.6.21
httplib2==0.8
lxml==3.2.0
oauthlib==0.5.1
oneconf==0.3.5
pexpect==2.4
piston-mini-client==0.7.5
protobuf==2.4.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycrypto==2.6
pycups==1.9.63
pycurl==7.19.0
pygobject==3.10.0
pyinotify==0.9.3
pyserial==2.6
pysmbc==1.0.13
python-apt==0.8.9.1ubuntu1
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu1
pyxdg==0.25
reportlab==2.6
rhythmbox-ubuntuone==13.10
roman==1.4.0
rubber==1.1
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
six==1.3.0
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
stevedore==0.14.1
system-service==0.1.6
ubuntuone-storage-protocol==13.10
unity-lens-photos==1.0
virtualenv==1.11.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
xdiagnose==3.6.1
zope.interface==4.0.5
johnk@johnk-HP-EliteBook-
```

terminal output below

```
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l /tmp/bootstrap_graphite_web"
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
    [production.foo.com] executing command
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Traceback (most recent call last):
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] execute_manager(settings)
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] utility.execute()
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] __import__(name)
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from django.db import models
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] 
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] return import_module('.base', backend_name)
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] __import__(name)
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 13, in <module>
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.creation import DatabaseCreation
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/creation.py", line 1, in <module>
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] import psycopg2.extensions
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions
```

Comment: did you do a simple google search of the error message before posting a question here ?

Comment: Ok. you have to install python psycopg2 before proceeding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728004/error-no-module-named-psycopg2-extensions

Comment: psycopg2==2.4.5 is installed on my machine.

Comment: are you using a virtualenv ? i mean activated ?

Comment: i think so this is what i have installed:                   virtualenv==1.11.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.2

Comment: Wierd. Looks right !!

Comment: im really lost, can't find anything on google that I have not already tried

Comment: I still believe it has not been installed. Can you try reinstalling it ?

Comment: looks like its installed I got "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"