# Pyscopg2 Module Not Found

Tags: python, django, iis, psycopg2

I hope someone can help me to resolve this issue.
I have a webapp developed in Django with postgresql, the app is working properly in my local pc, the issue started when i migrate the code into a server. 
I have a Windows Server 2019 core, and after configure the IIS to serve this app, appear the following issue:

**Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in 
    import psycopg2 as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'**

I have installed the connector "psycopg2" and also i already tried all that i found in "google" but i couldnt fix that issue.

SO i dont know if i forgot configure something in the IIS or what is happening here because if i open the python console or django shell and import the PSYCOPG2 the connector is imported successfully.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: is psycopg2 installed in same pyhton environment or different one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: No module named psycopg2.extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728004/error-no-module-named-psycopg2-extensions)

Comment: Make sure Python is added to your path, then make sure psycopg2 is installed with pip. E.g. pip install psycopg2

Comment: ELmahy, this is not my question. yes the psycopg2 is installed in both side into the pipenv and into a global server. Also i have istalled python 3.8 and djano 3.0.2

Comment: try to run python -m pip install psycopg2-binary command

Comment: Hi Panchal, i tried this command but is not working. i couldnt fix this issue yet, but its very weird because if i open the python console or django console  and try import psycopg2 is working as expected.

Comment: i could fix this issue. The issue was generated because i had 2 pythons installation. so the solution was delete all related with python and reinstall python and all libraries in one place.